# Call a function with std::function as argument with a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

The basis from my question I took from here:
[Failure to deduce template argument std::function from lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326206/failure-to-deduce-template-argument-stdfunction-from-lambda-function)
The question in this thread is:
Why this code can't pass the lambda to the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void call(std::function<void(T)> f, T v)
{
    f(v);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto foo = [](int i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    };
    call(foo, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The answer in this thread is, since a lambda isn't a `std::function`. But why is this code compiling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void call(std::function<void(T)> f, T v)
{
    f(v);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto foo = [](int i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    };
    call({foo}, 1); // changed foo to {foo}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the linked answer, the first version does not compile, because template argument deduction fails for the first argument; a lambda is never an `std::function<void(T)>`.

The second version compiles, because, by writing `{foo}`, `std::function<void(T)>` becomes a *non-deduced context*. So deduction can no longer fail for the first argument, as it isn't even attempted. So `T` is deduced as `int` solely from the second argument, and the call succeeds, because the lambda is convertible to an `std::function<void(int)>`.

From [temp.deduct.type]:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - ...
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list but the parameter
>     does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified.

Comment: So a call to `template <typename T> call(std::function<void(T)> f)` with a lambda would fail right?

Comment: And it would fail if `std::function` would have a constructor with `std::initializer_list` as argument?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter here. Deduction from an initializer list argument only happens if the parameter is itself an initializer list or an array. For instance: `template <typename T> max(std::initializer_list<T> values)` can deduce `T = int` from `max({1, 2, 3})`.

Comment: Nice man, so `template <typename T> void call(decltype(std::function<void(T)>{}) f, T v)` with `call([](int a) {}, 1)` should work as well. I currently feel like I rediscovered the wheel. So many years C++ and then this. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. Additionally, the future-standard-approved way of introducing a non-deduced context is using [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity)